# How to communicate between an iOS app and the WatchKit extension by storing the "reply" block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

One of the problems in `WatchKit` is communicating from the main app to the `WatchKit` extension. Some of the ways to do by sending Darwin notifications or with `MMWormhole`.

Could it be possible to do it by storing a reply block, sent by the extension to `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest`, on a property? Something like:

```
@property (atomic,copy) void (^watchKitReply)(NSDictionary *);
```

Then, when the app wants to send something to the extension, it uses this readily available block.

If the extension wants to communicate with the main app it will send a new reply block, that will be stored on the property. The old one will be used and discarded.

If not, why this isn't possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely do this. I would be careful though not to stomp your `watchKitReply` property each time and create a different way to allow multiple `reply` objects.

What we did in our Watch Extension / iOS App integration was to create a `WatchKitRequest` set of requests. Each reply block is then forwarded to each `WatchKitRequest` subclass where the request implementation is executed, then the `reply` block is executed when it is complete. Essentially we're doing exactly what you suggested which is store the `reply` block until you actually need to call it. We're just storing the `reply` block a bit differently than you suggested.

This approach worked extremely well for us. Hopefully this helps keep you moving in the right direction.

Comment: I would be very interested in more details on this. In my tests, having a pending reply block stopped any further communications.

Comment: I'm still testing, but it seems you need to use the replies block on the same order that they are produced. If you use a more recent one it will be pending until the old ones are dispatched.

Comment: That is very interesting. I never noticed that this was occurring with the way I built my system. I did not pass the information through the reply, but instead through MMWormhole. This allowed me to watch for data changes and parse those changes in a single workflow. If I would return the request data in the reply block, then I would have to parse the data there, as well as in the location where I was monitoring the MMWormhole notifications. It made it much easier to handle everything in a single location. The downside was that I didn't notice that order mattered.

Comment: I think my problem might have been more to do with the fact that my app is page-based. If the reply block is supposed to go back to a different page, then I think it has problems.